# Javascript url to open div when arrive from specific url

Tags: javascript, php, html

I was wondering if it was possible to use "Javascript URL",

Like this:

http://example.com/index.php#login-failed

and this makes input red and shows "login failed, try again" or something like that ?

Comment: *"I was wondering if it was possible"* Yes it is possible. Learn about `window.location.hash`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This??

```
if(window.location.hash == "#login-failed")
{
    var message = document.getElementById("your_message_element");
    message.innerHTML = "Login failed, try again";
    message.style.color = "red";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
if ( window.location.hash === '#login-failed' ) {
    alert( 'Your login just failed a lot.' );
}
```

To check the current hash, which is propably what you describe as a "Javascript Url".

Also you may want to have a look at the [window.onhashchange()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers.onhashchange) event.

Answer (score 0):

Window.location all examples

```
window.location = {
        hash: '#myAnchor',
        host: 'davidwalsh.name',
        hostname: 'davidwalsh.name',
        href: 'http://davidwalsh.name:80/article.php?s=david+walsh+blog#myAnchor',
        pathname: '/article.php',
        port: '80',
        protocol: 'http:',
        search: '?s=david+walsh+blog',
        replace: 'function replace() { [native code] }',
        assign: 'function assign() { [native code] }',
        reload: 'function reload() { [native code] }'
    }
```

in yout case :

```
window.location.href="http://example.com/index.php#login-failed";
```